# Acts_As_Taggable_On tag cloud for multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-taggable-on

I have two models (Image and Video) that both are setup to Act_As_Taggable.

I'd like to use the tags for these two models to generate one overall tag cloud (Images and Videos are being used as Assets in the application but I have separate models so that I can control mimetypes and post processing easier).

What's the best way to handle something like this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you followed [this blog post](http://juixe.com/techknow/index.php/2006/07/15/acts-as-taggable-tag-cloud/) and if you are able to extract the tags for each of the models individually, then all you need to do is merge the arrays and pass it to the `tag_cloud` method as given in the link.

Comment: I've actually just been using the tag_counts_on function (which seems to be an implementation of the post you included).  The only problem is that when I do a | union on the tag counts it doesn't add the counts together (it just removes duplicates from the two arrays).  What's the best way to do that?

Comment: Don't do a union. Do an OR using `+`. `@image_tags + @video_tags`

Comment: @Chirantan, I have used + operator and it works fine. But how to sort the whole fetched items from the both models.(Applying scope to each model sorts one full model and then the next model and returns in an array of first model and then the next model.But how to apply the sort to the retrieved whole fetched items)